# What is the meaning of `!!empty?`?

Tags: ruby, boolean, negation

ActiveSupport extends `Object` with an instance method `blank?`:

```
class Object
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
  end
end
```

Could `!!empty?` be written as `empty?` instead? Is this a stylistic choice so that it reads easily as a method returning a boolean? Or is there something else?

Comment: I presume you recognize that the operative line is the same as `self.respond_to?(:empty?)? !!self.empty? : !self` ? I don't understand why `!!` is needed since `empty?` returns a Boolean.

Comment: Good job reading code and clarifying any doubts. This is a great way to learn new languages.

Comment: I've reopened the question because it is a bit different. The OP specifically asks why `!!` is needed in conjunction with a predicate method that is supposed to return a boolean value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that `!!` coerces the response from empty to a boolean. Empty can be defined differently on different objects so it is possible that someone in rails could have defined `.empty?` to not return a boolean. Since `.blank?` needs to return a boolean the `!!` is needed to ensure that a boolean is returned.

Answer (score 4):

It is a common way to convert a truthy versus falesy value into strict `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common approach in Ruby to call `!!(something)`. The result of the calculation will be boolean, not nil or something else:

```
!!(true) # true
!!(false) # false
!!(nil) # false
```

Answer (score 2):

`!!` is used to force falsey/truthy values to false/true:

```
irb(main):001:0> !!nil == false
=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it used to be `empty?`. Here's the commit that changed it to `!!empty?`: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/126dc47665c65cd129967cbd8a5926dddd0aa514

From the [comments](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/126dc47665c65cd129967cbd8a5926dddd0aa514#commitcomment-13182895):

> **Bartuz:**
>   Why double `!!` ? It returns the `TrueClass` / `FalseClass` anynway
>
> **fxn:**
>   Because it is a dynamic language and subject to polymorphism, you just can't rely on `empty?` returning singletons, what you need to guarantee is that you return one no matter what.

The "improved" implementation however is incomplete, because you could just as well implement `!` to return a non-boolean value:

```
class Foo
  def !
    nil
  end
end

Foo.new.blank? #=> nil
```

To handle both methods (`empty?` and `!`), it should be implemented as:

```
!!(respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self)
```

Comment: You should also post a comment at the github page.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right, I've opened a pull request.